# How do you export/import variables from one form to another in C#?

Tags: c#

I made 2 forms in C# and I need to export some variables in one of them and import them to another. I keep hitting google but All I get is something about 'Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable'. Is this the right method to do?

Comment: why dont you create a third class, and store and read variables from that class? You would need to create a singleton object to that class.

Comment: *Is this the right method to do?* - no. Think about literally every other time in C# that you passed data around inside your app. Look at: `Console.WriteLine("Hello world")` - did we load "Hello world" into a system environment variable and then call `Console.WriteLine()` and it went and picked the data up out of the environment variable? No.. Forms are not special; theyre classes like everything else. They can have properties you can assign data to (they do already:  `yourForm.Text = "form title"`). They can have methods you call and pass data to (they do already: `form.Show(ownerForm)`)

Comment: So all you need to do is provide methods or properties on your form B and call them from your form A, passing the relevant data

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard! That makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your value one form to another form. you don't need to pass variable.

Exporter Activity code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,typeof(Activity2));      
i.PutExtra("Name",txt_Name.Text.ToString());    
StartActivity(i);
```

Importer Activity code:

```
string name = Intent.GetStringExtra("Name");    
txt_Result.Text ="Hello, "+name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want, but you could pass arguments like:

```
Form form2 = new Form(argument); //pass an argument
form2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

And in the second form is like:

```
public Form2(string argument){
    InitializeComponent();
    // do whatever you want with passed argument
}
```

Or you can create a public static variable, like:

```
// in the main form
public static int value = 2;
```

And in the second form:

```
int value2 = Form.value;
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Don't necessarily agree with the *static* part of the "create a public static variable" vrecommendation. Public things in C# should use PascalCase please..

Comment: If it gives me "Inaccessible due to its protection level" it's because I didn't used public/private well?

Comment: Don't use the "static" advice, that's poor advice in my opinion